# Anylogic - how to share resource pool?

Tags: resources, simulation, anylogic, shared, bank

I'm working on a simulation of the bank, and this model has two tasks: 'deposit and withdrawal' and 'consultation'. Since there are more customers in the 'deposit and withdrawal' business, I would like to set up a resource pool so that the server in the 'consultation' business can go and help if the server in the 'deposit and withdrawal business' is insufficient. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epYSw.png)

Answer (score 0):

the service block has the option of alternative resources so you can do the following:

[image: this]

Comment: thank you very much.
Thanks to you I solved this problem.